# ¿como generar alertas de vencimiento de fechas?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

hola anteriormente me ayudaron con esto de las alertas pero no entiendo muy bien el concepto de los objetos datatime:diff soy muy novato para esto de la programación se que debe de ser algo sencillo pero no encuentro como realizar esto.

ya logre hacer que en mi tabla se muestre los mantenimientos a vencer cuando faltan 2 y un día pero si pongo el ultimo if el de mantenimiento vencido ya no funciona y aparte cuando faltan mas días para que se venza el mantenimiento no se como poner la validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les dejo el código de mi tabla:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());
$query="SELECT  * FROM mantenimiento ORDER BY id_mtto DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

  $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));//nueva variable para vencimiento//

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

  $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['fecha_final']);
  $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');

    // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
    if ($dias <= 0) {
    $status= "Mantenimiento vencido";
    } 
    elseif ($dias <= 2) {
    $status= "Está a " . $dias . " días de vencer";
    }
    if ($dias <=1) {
    $status= "Mañana vence";
    }

$datos=$row['id_mtto']."||".
$row['vehiculo']."||".
$row['servicio']."||".
$row['tipo_mtto']."||".
$row['observaciones']."||".
$row['fecha_inicio']."||".
$row['fecha_final'];
?>
  <tr> 
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['id_mtto']?></td>  
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['vehiculo']?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['servicio']?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['tipo_mtto']?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['observaciones']?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['fecha_inicio']?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo$row['fecha_final']?></td>
    <td class="text-center">
    <?php echo $status?>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En parte te lo respondí en la otra pregunta.

El problema es la forma en la que están los `if` donde definís `$status`.

Lo primero es entender que con la clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) creamos un objeto a partir de una fecha. Ese objeto trae un montón de métodos (funciones) que nos permiten realizar distintas operaciones con las fechas. Uno de esos métodos es [`diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php).

Supongamos:

```
$hoy = new DateTime('2019-06-01');
$final = new DateTime('2019-06-11');
```

Entre una fecha y la otra hay 10 días de diferencia. Eso es exactamente lo que calcula [`diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php).

```
$diferencia = $hoy->diff($final);
```

Hasta ahí estamos guardando la *diferencia* entre una fecha y la otra. Pero podemos elegir en que unidad expresar dicha diferencia. Podríamos expresarla en horas, años, etc. Vos lo que necesitás es calcular la diferencia en días, eso lo definimos con [`format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php).

```
$dias = $diferencia->format('%r%a');
```

Qué significa cada una de las letras del `format()`?

> r | Signo "-" cuando es negativo, vacío cuando es positivo
>
> a | Número total de días como resultado de una operación con DateTime::diff(), o de lo contrario (unknown)

Eso significa que `$dias` nos puede dar un número positivo (sin el signo `+`) o un número negativo con el signo `-`. Con eso podemos armar los `if` para decidir que mensaje mostrar.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, vos estás evaluando si:

- $dias es menor o igual a 0. Eso se daría si las dos fechas son iguales (0) o si el evento ya pasó (número negativo).
- $dias es menor o igual a 2. Es decir, si faltan 2 o menos días (pero no 0 ni menos de 0 porque eso lo descartaste arriba).
- $dias es menor o igual a 1. Acá tenés u problema porque ese `if` no está relacionado con el anterior. No pasa nada, pero debería estar antes de `<= 2`

El problema es que NO estás contemplando si `$dias` es MAYOR a 2. En dicho caso no deberías mostrar ningun mensaje, pero no estás definiendo `$status`, por eso te aparece un error indicando que `$status no está definido`.

Cómo arreglarlo?

```
if ($dias <= 0) {
    $status= "Mantenimiento vencido";
} elseif ($dias == 1) {
    $status= "Mañana vence";
} elseif ($dias <= 2) {
    $status= "Está a " . $dias . " días de vencer";
} else {
    $status = '';
}
```

Por lo único que dejo `<= 2` es por si el día de mañana querés que muestre un mensaje faltando `3` días en vez de `2`. Con solo cambiar eso sería suficiente, el mensaje sería el mismo.

Comment: ande muchas gracias por responder nuevamente y muy buena explicación ya me quedo mas claro el manejo del datatime , diff , format , ya quedo lo que quería hacer